# Openbackupevent log failing with rpc error

Tags: winapi, rpc, event-log

OpenBackupEventLog failing in one system, but same code is working in another

```
> I tried to read event logs saved in the file AppEvent.evtx using c++ code
> HANDLE hEventLog = OpenBackupEventLog( NULL, "D:\\AppEvent.evtx" );
> Sucessfully compiled but getting run time rpc error, open failed.
> But call is getting failed with error code 1722 and sometimes 1726.
> Both are rpc related.
> Checked below Rpc services and all running properly.

Remote Procedure Call (RPC);
RPC Endpoint Mapper;
DCOM Server Process Launcher;
Confirmed that all services are running.
```

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.